# Initializing the first element in a struct

Tags: c++

I do a lot of Win32 programming in C++ and many Win32 structures have a 'size' (often called `cbSize` or `length`) member as the first element which needs to be set before the relevant API call can be made.  For example:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wp;
wp.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
GetWindowPlacement(hWnd, &wp);
```

Now, I think it is good practice to initialize structure members to zero which I can do with:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = { };
```

or

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = { 0 };
```

However, what happens to the other members of the struct if I initialize the first member like this:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = { sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT) };
```

Are they automatically initialized to zero?  Or does it depend on which compiler I'm using and whether it's a debug build or not?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, they're automatically initialized to zero.

8.5.1/7:

> If there are fewer initializers in the
>   list than there are members in the
>   aggregate, then each member not
>   explicitly initialized shall be
>   value-initialized (8.5). [Example:

```
struct S { int a; char* b; int c; };
S ss = { 1, "asdf" };
```

> initializes ss.a with 1, ss.b with
>   "asdf", and ss.c with the value of an
>   expression of the form int(), that is,
>   0. ]

Comment: +1 for the quotation. I was searching for that, but I quoted it :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the size is the first element, this will be ok. Any members that don't get a value in the initializer will be zeroed.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = { X };
```

Will initialize all remaining members to 0 (assuming POD).

See: 8.5.1 Aggregates [dcl.init.aggr] Paragraph: 7:

> 7 If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member not explicitly initialized shall be value-initialized (8.5).
>
> [ Example:

```
   struct S { int a; char* b; int c; };
   S ss = { 1, "asdf" };
```

> initializes ss.a with 1, ss.b with "asdf", and ss.c with the value of an expression of the form int(), that
> is, 0. —end example ]

Comment: Clearly Rob already knows that, he's asking whether `WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = { sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT) };` initializes the remaining members to zero (it does).